# How to get data from API fast?

Tags: python, pandas, api

I am now trying to get votes data from http://parldata.eu/api/ by using spyder. However, the data is very large and it might cost me several weeks to run the code in Spyder on my notebook. Is there any solution that can help me to collect these data in one day? Thank you!

My code is as below, I use the parliament() and getall() functions from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KohoVolit/api.parldata.eu/master/client/vpapi.py

```
import vpapi
import csv
import pandas as pd

##set the country and party
country = 'cz'
party = 'senat'
vpapi.parliament(country+'/'+party)

## store data to df5, there are 11 million records in the dataset.
## This process is slow.
df5 = pd.DataFrame()
vote = vpapi.getall('votes')
for item in vote:
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(item, orient='index')
    df5 = df5.append(df_temp.T)
```

Comment: Pay for a faster Internet connection.

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify it? My Internet Speed is 20 mbps. And the whole dataset is about 1GB. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Take a look at [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/use-cases.html)